# Why does EF & NUnit throw an Exception if I try and use TransactionScope in a parent class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit

If I do the following:

```
public class AIntegrationTests
{

    protected TransactionScope transaction = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        transaction.Dispose();
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTests : AIntegrationTests
{
    private UserRepository _sut;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _sut = new UserRepository();

    }

    //tests
}
```

I get this error:

```
 network access for distributed transaction manager (msdtc) has been disabled 
Please enable Network DTC access because of qlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table) 
for particular database
```

When I remove the transaction instantiation from the parent class and put it back in the child 
I get no errors.

```
public class AIntegrationTests
{

    protected TransactionScope transaction = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        transaction.Dispose();
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTests : AIntegrationTests
{
    private UserRepository _sut;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _sut = new UserRepository();
       transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required);
    }

    //tests
}
```

Why am I not allowed to instantiate transaction in the parent class. If I leave the Dispose call in 
the parent it works fine.

Comment: For the second example, what happens if you move the constructor of `TransactionScope` before `UserRepository`? I believe the base class Setup method will be called before the derived class Setup method, so the two aren't exactly equivalent right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetUp()` in the derived class is hiding `SetUp()` in the base class, so `AIntegrationTests`'s `SetUp()` is never called. Explicitly call it from `UserRepositoryIntegrationTests`'s `SetUp()`...

```
[TestFixture]
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTests : AIntegrationTests
{
    private UserRepository _sut;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _sut = new UserRepository();
        base.SetUp();
    }

    //tests
}
```

Since you have control over both classes, you should make the `SetUp()` `virtual` in the base class and override it...

```
public class AIntegrationTests
{

    protected TransactionScope transaction = null;

    [SetUp]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        transaction.Dispose();
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTests : AIntegrationTests
{
    private UserRepository _sut;

    [SetUp]
    public override void SetUp()
    {
        _sut = new UserRepository();
        base.SetUp();
    }

    //tests
}
```